# Prevent "guessing mono" when using FFMPEG?

Tags: python, ffmpeg, discord.py

This extention works perfectly fine, I'm just concerned about the message it prints everytime it's called.

`The Message when the script is called:`

```
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.0 : mono
```

This is an extention to the discord bot I'm working on using `discord.py`.

`Script`

```py
from discord.ext import commands
from pyttsx3 import init  # TTS Audio converter

import discord


ffmpeg_path = r"C:\Users\evand\Documents\Misc\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe"

audio_path = r"C:\Users\evand\Documents\Misc\Discord\suhj_bot\Test_mp3\AudioFileForDiscord.mp3"


engine = init() # Initializes speach TTS engine with "sapi5" configuration


def TTS_save(text, audio=engine): # converts and saves the user's text into a TTS audio file ".mp3"

    audio.save_to_file(text, audio_path)

    audio.runAndWait()


class Voice(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, bot):

        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command(

        name="v",
        description="The voice command:\n\ng.v <content>"

    )

    async def voice_command(self, ctx, *, args):

        VoiceClient = ctx.voice_client


        if VoiceClient is None:

            VoiceClient = await ctx.author.voice.channel.connect() # bot joins voice-channel of user


        TTS_save(args) # creates TTS audio file

        VoiceClient.play(discord.FFmpegOpusAudio(audio_path, executable=ffmpeg_path)) # plays audio file through discord bot (.mp3, ffmpeg.exe)

        return


def setup(bot):

    bot.add_cog(Voice(bot))
```

Is there any way to prevent the program from *guessing* mono?  I like to keep my code clean and close to errorness.